# operator== does not compile if I include <iostream>

Tags: c++, iostream

The following code compiles perfectly if:

1. I don't include `<iostream>` or
2. I name `operator==` as `alp::operator==`.

I suppose there is a problem with `<iostream>` and `operator==`, but I don't know what.

I compile the code with gcc 7.3.0, clang++-6.0 and goldbolt. Always the same error.

The problem is that the compiler is trying to cast the parameters of `operator==` to `const_iterator`, but why? (I suppose the compiler doesn't see my version of `operator==`, and looks for other versions).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> // comment and compile


namespace alp{

template <typename It_base>
struct Iterator {
    using const_iterator    = Iterator<typename It_base::const_iterator>;

    operator const_iterator() { return const_iterator{}; }
};


template <typename It_base>
bool operator==(const Iterator<It_base>& x, const Iterator<It_base>& y)
{ return true;}

}// namespace

struct Func{
    int& operator()(int& p) const {return p;}
};


template <typename It, typename View>
struct View_iterator_base{
    using return_type     = decltype(View{}(*It{})); 

    using const_iterator =
              View_iterator_base<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, Func>;
};


using view_it =
    alp::Iterator<View_iterator_base<std::vector<int>::iterator, Func>>;


int main()
{
    view_it p{};
    view_it z{};

    bool x = operator==(z, p); // only compiles if you remove <iostream>
    bool y = alp::operator==(z,p); // always compile
}
```

Error message:

```
yy.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct View_iterator_base<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >, Func>’:

yy.cpp:9:73:   required from ‘struct    alp::Iterator<View_iterator_base<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >, Func> >’

yy.cpp:44:29:   required from here

yy.cpp:28:42: error: no match for call to ‘(Func) (const int&)’
 using return_type   = decltype(View{}(*It{}));
                                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
yy.cpp:22:10: note: candidate: int& Func::operator()(int&) const <near match>
 int& operator()(int& p) const {return p;}
      ^~~~~~~~
yy.cpp:22:10: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
yy.cpp:28:42: error: binding reference of type ‘int&’ to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers
 using return_type   = decltype(View{}(*It{}));
                                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Comment: The program is ill-formed regardless of whether `<iostream>` is included. I don't know why those compilers fail to diagnose the issue when it isn't included.

Comment: And why is ill-formed?

Comment: The problem, as mentioned by @Artyer, is on the `using const_iterator =
              View_iterator_base<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, Func>;` line. Here you have a `const_iterator` you try to pass to `Func`.

Comment: Yes I know. This is an `iterator`, so I need to provide `iterator` and `const_iterator` and an implicit cast from `iterator` to `const_iterator`. Bur in my code I'm not using `const_iterator`. Is the compiler who tries to convert iterator to `const_iterator` when I call    `operator==`

Comment: The compiler needs it while instantiating your template. You can see it if you try to explicitly instantiate it like: `namespace alp {
template struct Iterator<View_iterator_base<std::vector<int>::iterator, Func>>;
}` It'll fail no matter whether you include `iostrema`or not. our program is just ill-formed.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a more minimal test case here: https://godbolt.org/z/QQonMG .

The relevant details are:

- A `using` type alias does *not* instantiate a template. So for example:

  ```
  template<bool b>
  struct fail_if_true {
      static_assert(!b, "template parameter must be false");
  };

  using fail_if_used = fail_if_true<true>;
  ```

  will not cause a compile time error (if `fail_if_used` isn't used)
- ADL also inspects template parameter classes. In this case, `std::vector<int>::iterator` is `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >, Func>`, which has a `std::vector<int>` in it's template. So, `operator==` will check in the global namespace (always), `alp` (As `alp::Iterator` is in `alp`), `__gnu_cxx` and `std`.
- Your `View_iterator_base::const_iterator` is invalid. `View_iterator_base::const_interator::result_type` is defined as `decltype(Func{}(*std::vector<int>::const_iterator{}))`. `std::vector<int>::const_iterator{}` will be a vectors const iterator, so `*std::vector<int>::const_iterator{}` is a `const int&`. `Func::operator()` takes an `int&`, so this means that the expression is invalid. But it won't cause a compile time error if not used, for the reasons stated above. This means that your conversion operator is to an invalid type.
- Since you don't define it as `explicit`, the conversion operator (To an invalid type) will be used to try and match it to the function parameters if they don't already match. Obviously this will finally instantiate the invalid type, so it will throw a compile time error.
- My guess is that `iostream` includes `string`, which defines `std::operator==` for strings.

Here's an example without the `std` namespace: https://godbolt.org/z/-wlAmv

```
// Avoid including headers for testing without std::
template<class T> struct is_const { static constexpr const bool value = false; } template<class T> struct is_const<const T> { static constexpr const bool value = true; }

namespace with_another_equals {
    struct T {};

    bool operator==(const T&, const T&) {
        return true;
    }
}

namespace ns {
    template<class T>
    struct wrapper {
        using invalid_wrapper = wrapper<typename T::invalid>;
        operator invalid_wrapper() {}
    };

    template<class T>
    bool operator==(const wrapper<T>&, const wrapper<T>&) {
        return true;
    }
}

template<class T>
struct with_invalid {
    static_assert(!is_const<T>::value, "Invalid if const");
    using invalid = with_invalid<const T>;
};

template<class T>
void test() {
    using wrapped = ns::wrapper<with_invalid<T>>;
    wrapped a;
    wrapped b;
    bool x = operator==(a, b);
    bool y = ns::operator==(a, b);
}

template void test<int*>();

// Will compile if this line is commented out
template void test<with_another_equals::T>();
```

Note that just declaring `operator const_iterator()` should instantiate the type. But it doesn't because it is within templates. My guess is that it is optimised out (where it does compile because it's unused) before it can be checked to show that it can't compile (It doesn't even warn with `-Wall -pedantic` that it doesn't have a return statement in my example).